# Frequency Table for Repeated Measures

Tags: repeated-measures, sas, frequency

I've 12 unique subjects, and in total I've almost 1700 observations.

I've an ordinal response variable (has 4 levels) and 3 categorical covariates (each one has different levels 3, 5, 2, and 4 respectively).

The values of response and covariates are changing for any unique subject.

What's the best way to present the frequency of this data set?

Comment: I'm not getting this. Could you maybe give an example of what the data look like? I don't see how you are getting 1700 observations with 4 levels of 3 categorical variables, so I think I'm missing something here. Are there repetitions for each individual over time?

Comment: Think of it as we collect four variables (response, X1, X2, and X3) for each subject, and we have 15 subjects, so without repeating, we'll end up with 15 rows of data, however, since we deal with repeated measure (yes, over time).. we ended up with 1700 rows of data.

Comment: I see. In effect, you have a multivariate time series (4 series per person). It's a bit tricky, given that you can't assume normality (categorical covariates and ordinal.response). What do you mean by presenting the frequency of the data set? You could simply take the average over everyone's repeated measures and contemplate the results. Sample size of 12 (or 15) for the number of subjects.

Comment: Comment continued. The first think I would do would be to study the correlation structure of the repeated measures and the cross correlations between response and covariate series, to see if there is any structure worth modeling there. If you can legitimately average across repetitions, then you have a simple multiple regression scenario, with more or less normal variables, thanks to your averages and the central limit theory.